# Downloading: connection...Failed to download cartalyst/nested-sets from dist:

Tags: laravel-4, composer-php

I'm having some problems with a package (cartalyst/nested-sets) on my local laravel application. My `composer.json` is valid as:

```
$ composer validate
./composer.json is valid
```

I have a copy of the nested-sets package files on my desktop and have included them in my project tree - so the files are present and paths are correct.

Here's a snapshot of my `composer.json` file:

```
"require": {          
        "cartalyst/nested-sets": "2.0.*"
},
    "repositories": [
    {
    "type": "composer",
            "url": "http://packages.cartalyst.com"
  }
],
...
```

I then issue:

```
$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
- Installing cartalyst/nested-sets (v2.0.2)
Downloading: connection...Failed to download cartalyst/nested-sets from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/cartalyst/nested-sets/zipball/7a425710ece922556e55150f5a1f2dfbedd4ffaa" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)
Now trying to download from source
- Installing cartalyst/nested-sets (v2.0.2)
Cloning 7a425710ece922556e55150f5a1f2dfbedd4ffaa
```

It then just hangs with a blinking cursor at the shell. PHP OpenSSL extension is installed on my local and switching the firewall off makes no difference.

From the shell:

`Failed to download cartalyst/nested-sets from dist: file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)` but the files are already there? I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You encounter this problem because you have to subscribe to Cartalyst repositories so you can get full access of their ressources and products ( libraries , components , sources ).

When Composer is trying to fetch Cartalyst from donwload or accessing a repository , it will ask you a valid username / password , if you have paid for a subscription you will get a valid auth credentials that enable you to access the repository and donwload via composer the required component / library ...

please read the following : https://medium.com/@Cartalyst/boss-sheet-8019c5e07246

Comment: Composer is not asking me for a username/password. It just errors out.